# Organic Groups module  messes up node editing

Tags: 7, organic-groups

**Updated header to reflect real cause of problem**

I've created some content types using node references for "belongs to" or "owned by" relationships.

When I add a new node, selecting the node references seems to work fine, and the default "list view" showing the newly created nodes also shows that the relationsship is correct. However, when I try to view or edit a single node, the form displayed includes only the "Title" field, and nothing else. I've also verified through "Manage fields" and "Manage display" that my node reference field is supposed to be displayed, but it still does not seem to work.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Stack Exchange is not a replacement for the issue queue. If you continue to have trouble, [file an issue](http://drupal.org/project/issues/references).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just figured out that the problem was not caused by the references module, but by the "Organic Groups" (og) module. It seems to be a known bug in the organic groups module that basically hides/disables all fields for custom content types that are not marked as group or something like that. There's a report about this in http://drupal.org/node/1029230.

Disabling the organic module make the fields come back again, and even relationships seems to be editable again. I can live without organic groups for now, and considering the severity of the bug I will definitively not try to use that module again until it has been fixed.

Comment: I just learned that the OG module also messes up the Token module somewhat (found it while using auto_nodetitle). I guess using OG is for the very brave at this stage...

Answer (score 1):

FYI - this question is in reference to the new D7 "References" module (http://drupal.org/project/references) which is currently in development and has not had a formal release. Have you taken a look in the issues cue for the module related to your problem: http://drupal.org/project/issues/references?categories=All

Comment: Yes, I've looked at it, but didn't manage to figure out whether editing nodes was supported or not. There are references to views etc, but apart from actually trying to use the module, I'm not qualified to say whether those view issues are related to custom views, the views module or anything else. Creating a node works as expected, editing does not. I am trying to figure out whether that is a feature (of the module in it's current state) or whether it is a bug. If you see an issue that answers this, feel free to point me in the right direction. Thanks.